# Can roots of quintic polynomials be a solution of radicals?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quintics

Assuming integer co-efficients, does there exist a solution to a quintic polynomial that is a solution of radicals? I understand that there is no *general* formula to solve any quintic, but that doesn't necessarily mean that roots cannot be expressed in an algebraic formula. i.e one root may be $\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt[3]{54}}$ and the other may be $\sqrt{33+\sqrt[5]{2}}$. That doesn't necessarily mean that they come from one single general formula.

Note: I am not familiar with the proof itself.

Comment: The title of your question confuses me. Roots of polynomials with integer coefficients are by definition algebraic numbers.

Comment: "Non-algebraic" means something else, namely not a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. You mean "solvable by radicals", and yes, an example of a quintic whose roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals is $x^5 − x + 1 = 0$.​

Comment: @MartinR Yh no sorry, I made a mistake complicated to explain. I've fixed it

Comment: The title is still false. Roots of quintic polynomials over $\Bbb Z$ cannot be transcendental. As Martin said, they are algebraic.

Comment: I think you're conflating "algebraic" with "expressible by radicals." Some quintics have roots which are not expressible by radicals; however, no (non-zero) quintic has a root which is non-algebraic (= transcendental).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for that. I have changed it

Comment: So I first knew that transcendental=algebraic. Then Dietrich pointed out the acc definition of algebraic so I thought transcendental $\neq$ algebraic; I first thought that transcendental meant 'cannot be expressed by simple algebra', It never occurred to me to look up the formal definition, much less that it would be one in terms of polynomial solutions, hence the confusion.

Comment: All roots of the quintic equation $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5) = 0$ are expressible in terms of radicals (in the usual sense). In fact, all roots of this quintic equation are positive integers (single digit integers, even).

Comment: From Renfro’s comment: For a number defined by radicals $r_i$, multiply any $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)(x-r_5)$ and you will have a quintic with radical roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the usual proof of the Abel--Ruffini theorem shows, that for some particular choice of quintic (for example $x^5 - x - 1$) its roots cannot be written as expression involving arithmetic operations, radicals, and rational numbers (this of course implies the 'no general formula' version).